# How can we override cache_set() in drupal 7

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, cache-control

I have a drupal 7 application. I need to block the insertion of cache in `cache_form` table. So how can we override `cache_set()` in drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can't override `cache_set()`, what you can do is use a custom cache backend for the `cache_form` cache bin. If you don't want to cache anything for `cache_form`, you can use a simple implementation whose methods do nothing.

```
class DoNothingCache extends DrupalCacheInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  function get($cid) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  function getMultiple(&$cids) {
    return array();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  function set($cid, $data, $expire = CACHE_PERMANENT) {}


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  function clear($cid = NULL, $wildcard = FALSE) {}

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  function isEmpty() {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

The `cache_class_cache_form` configuration variable defines the class, implementing the [`DrupalCacheInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/interface/DrupalCacheInterface/7) interface, to use for the `cache_form` bin. You can set it in your settings.php file.

```
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DoNothingCache';
```